# Login form with only php and html and user and pass id in a .txt file

Tags: php, html, authentication, text-files

so I'm trying to create a login form with only html, php and txt files (I can't use a database for this assignment).
I'm new to php but i have kinda got i to work. 
My txt file looks like name|password for example:

```
Jacob|transport
Lars|griskraft
```

The problem i have is that it works with the last name|password combo in my txt file but not with another name and password combo before them.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
$userN = $_POST ['name'];
$passW = $_POST ['password'];

// Puts the whole array in a file every new line is an array
$userlist = file ( 'users.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );

// Defines a boolean success to false
$success = false;

foreach ( $userlist as $user ) {
    $user_details = explode ( '|', $user);
    //if ($user_details [0] == $userN && $user_details [1] == $passW) {
    if ((in_array($userN, $user_details) and (in_array($passW,     $user_details)))) {
        $success = true;
        echo $success . " is: ";
        break;
    }
}
if ($success) {
    echo "<br> Hi $userN you have been logged in. <br>";
} else {
    echo "<br> You have entered the wrong username or password. Please try again. <br>";
}
}

?>
```

Here is the html form:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        Comments:
        <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="commentContent"></textarea>
        <br /> Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br /> Password: <input
            type="password" name="password" size="15" maxlength="30" /> <br /> <input
            type="submit" value="Post!"> <br />
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few empty/white spaces in .txt file, in first line, that was problem, so, `trim()` it:

```
foreach ( $userlist as $user ) {
    $user_details = explode ( '|', $user);

   if (trim($user_details [0]) == $userN && trim($user_details [1]) == $passW) {
    //if ((in_array($userN, $user_details) and (in_array($passW,     $user_details)))) {
        $success = true;
        echo $success . " is: ";
        break;
    }
}
```

`var_dump($user_details)` will show you that there are few more invisible chars...

Tested it, and now works fine.